# Entity Framework 4.1 Self Referencing

Tags: entity-framework-4

Given a POCO Product class:

```
public class Product {

    public int ProductId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

}
```

how can I enable related products using EF?

Basically, I need to allow product owners to add products that user may also be interested in.

I've tried adapting answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383576/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-self-referencing-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-as) but can't get it to work.

I think I need a link table as a product can have many products a user may be interested.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't the Product class have a ICollection of Products ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i must have been doing something wrong earlier.  I've re-visited option 1 from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383576/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-self-referencing-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-as) and its done exactly what i needed.