# Find top level entities in self referencing table

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

In Entity Framework, how do I search for objects that are at the top level in EF?

If I have a group of subassemblies that have subcomponents.  Those subassemblies can be placed in larger assemblies.

In a real world example: Let's say we build a cabinet with a computer and the computer has parts.  How do I find the computers that have not been installed in a cabinet or, perhaps, parts not installed in a computer?

```
public class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string PartId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Manufactured { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Component> SubComponents { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Interesting title you have.

Comment: Can you see the database structure it generated, if your `Component` table has a self referencing foreign key, you can check when that foreign key is null.  If that's the case, you would have to update your model to expose that information.

Comment: @hexacyanide: Have you ever killed an orphan in Linux? ;)

Comment: No orphans, just zombies.

Comment: Great point Matthew.  As I explained below I was trying to expose the foreign key in the wrong spot which was causing the error.

Comment: Fixed the title - "Children without Parents".  I will claim "tired programmer on a Saturday night". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found my answer here...[Self Referencing Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383576/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-self-referencing-one-to-many-and-many-to-many-as)

```
public class Component
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string PartId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Manufactured { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string ProductType { get; set; }

    //Added this...
    public int? ParentComponentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentComponentId")]
    public virtual Component ParentComponent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Component> SubComponents { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Originally I was trying to add a Foreign Key to the SubComponents but I actually needed a FK on the parent relationship.  Now my EF query looks like this...

```
return _db.Components.Where(x => x.ParentComponent == null).ToList();
```